# Regex - How to know if given letters are part of a word with custom % of coverage?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to build a Regex? that allows:

- check if letters of a word are part of a word in a given %

for example:

> Given: **Wrd** (note the absence of "o")
>
> And comparing with **Word**
>
> And given a % of match coverage = **60%**
>
> **Wrd** has **60%** (or more) of letters of **Word** = **True**

Now another case

> Given: **alarxyzwrd**
>
> And comparing with **Alargeword** (note that **alarxyzwrd** only matches **alarwrd** because **Alargeword** does not contains **xyz** letters (case doesn't matter)
>
> And given a % of match coverage = **80%**
>
> **alarxyzwrd** only has **70%** of **Alargeword**, Regex ignores this word or returns False.

order of letters to match are important, because if we try to match **aaaaaa** of **aloha** each "a" gives a percent of points that returns **100%** of coverage, which is wrong.

I hope exists a genius of Regex, to help me with this.

Comment: Are you only ever comparing a pair of words at a time?

Comment: if possible, compare a word with a sentence, but word to word is ok.

Comment: While this is an interesting topic, what have you tried yourself and why do you think regex is the way to go for this?

Comment: hi @ASDFGerte, as sad as it sounds, im not a Regex guy that is able to resolve this. I have searched a lot for this solution, no success, i think this is so helpful for everyone and helping to me is equals to help a lot of "search engines" of many systems that can implement search by regex, only of words that make sense and not that "matches" and many other cases.

Comment: regex is the way because you can't code in a database, but most of databases accept regex functions. even in code, you can use regex to cover this cases or many other cases.

Comment: A regex either matches a string (or substring) or it doesn't. If it does match it will tell you what substring matched. Regexes don't do "fuzzy matching" within X%.

Comment: Another question - do you want the presence of `'xyz'` in your example to reduce the percentage of the match? Or does it not matter? (To explain it another way, does `alarwrd` match higher than `alarxyzwrd`, or is it the same?)

Comment: hi @Beejamin, tnx for your interest, extra letters should not be considered in any way, just are extra or useless letters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my idea. You would build a regex from the given word, say `alarxyzwrd`, like this:

```
(.*?a)?(.*?l)?(.*?a)?(.*?r)?(.*?x)?(.*?y)?(.*?z)?(.*?w)?(.*?r)?(.*?d)?
```

Then match it against the text, say `"AlargeWord"`. You then count the number of subexpressions `(`...`)?` that matched. This will give you the percentage of the characters that matched in total. In my example the match returns 7 subexpressions that are not empty, that means 7 letters matched (ignore case). If you need to know what letters matched, you'll find them at the end of each submatch.

Comment: this is very close to the idea, i'm testing.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare word to word, hope this helps, see [regexp](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/regexp):

```js
Coverage('Alargeword', 'alarxyzwrd');
Coverage('word', 'Wrd');
Coverage('aloha', 'aaaaaa');

// Match chars: 
// [ 'A', 'l', 'a', 'r', 'w', 'r', 'd' ]
// Coverage: 
// alarxyzwrd has 70% of Alargeword
// 
// Match chars: 
// [ 'w', 'r', 'd' ]
// Coverage: 
// Wrd has 75% of word
// 
// Match chars: 
// [ 'a', 'a' ]
// Coverage: 
// aaaaaa has 40% of aloha

function Coverage(originWord, givenWord) {
    var givenString = givenWord.toLowerCase().split('').map(function (char) {
        if (originWord.indexOf(char) === -1) {
            return '[^' + char + ']*?(' + char + '?)';
        } else {
            return '[^' + char + ']*(' + char + '?)';
        }
    }).join('');

    var givenReg = new RegExp(givenString, 'i');

    var result = originWord.match(givenReg);

    var matchChars = result.slice(1).filter(function (char) {
        return char;
    });

    var coverage = matchChars.length / originWord.length;

    console.log('Match chars: ');
    console.log(matchChars);

    console.log('Coverage: ');
    console.log(givenWord + ' has ' + coverage*100 + '% of ' + originWord);
    console.log('');
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i'm looking for a Regex, because i need to pass the regex to the database query, code this problem with any program languaje is very easy. but thank you.

Comment: Is `givenReg` in the snippet the regex you want? It's generated by the given word.For `Wrd`, it will be  `/[^w]*(w?)[^r]*(r?)[^d]*(d?)/i`